# How can I give name for unknown number of inputs in html table?

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, forms

I have a form consist of tables which the inputs(rows) can be increased depends on the user needs, so I've used jquery and javascript finctions and I name them as follow: name="projectname[]" so that the names will be in an array but when I ran the page later on and added rows to the table to fill my information I realized that the array is not working because my radio buttons are affected by others row I mean like if I have two rows then there is only one who can be checked .. so they have the same name ! so what can I do ? [this is what I meant  only one is checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eIsh.png)

```
     function myfunction(x){
        var row = x.closest("tr");
        $("<tr><td></td> <td><input name='mainm[]'/> </td><td><input 
         type='radio' name='mainmfts[]' value='Y'> Yes<input type='radio' 
         name='mainmfts[]' value='N'> No</td> </tr>").insertAfter(row);

        $("#myform").on("click","TheSelectorForTheIcon",function(){
        var row = x.closest("tr");
        $("<tr>…</tr>").insertAfter(row);


        })               

    }
```

Comment: We don't have enough details to help you.  If you are later loading the page with the previously submitted daya, then you know exactly how many fields/rows to make via a looping technique.  Can't help you, not yet.  I don't know if advising a deeper array structure will help.  E.g. `mainmfts[i][]` with javascript keeping the row tally as `i`.

Comment: you didn't get my question ? or you need more codes ?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit unclear. Could you show what's happening now, and what would you like to achieve? You have a persistent array between page loads, but not a persistent form?

Comment: I might understand but I can't reproduce the issue.  We need more codes -- [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after so many tries I find out the simplest solution

```
        /*to get the table and the length of it (#rows)*/
         var table2 = document.getElementById("tblmain");
         var RowCount= table2.rows.length; 
         var row = x.closest("tr"); /*to insert the row after the current row */
```

after that I make the rowCount the index of the array

```
$("<tr> <td><input name='mainm["+RowCount+"]'/> </td> ).insertAfter(row);
   $("#myform").on("click","TheSelectorForTheIcon",function(){
        var rows = x.closest("tr");
         $("<tr>…</tr>").insertAfter(row); 

       })
```

for more info have a look at the code posted with the question

Answer (score 0):

You should have different name for each row. You can set name like `projectname[0]` for the first appearing input. When you are making clone, you can calculate existing rows and can change the name accordingly. Please refer to below code:

```
var replaceAll = function(string, replacingItem, replaceWith) {
     return string.toString().replace(new RegExp(replacingItem, 'g'), replaceWith);
};

function myfunction(x){

    /* Below code will work for first appearnace */
    var row = x.closest("tr");
    $("<tr><td></td> <td><input name='mainm[0]'/></td><td><input 
        type='radio' name='mainmfts[0]' value='Y'> Yes<input type='radio' 
        name='mainmfts[0]' value='N'> No</td> </tr>").insertAfter(row);
    /* End Code */

    $("#myform").on("click","TheSelectorForTheIcon",function(){
        var row = x.closest("tr");
        var cloneData = "<tr><td></td> <td><input name='mainm[{$key}]'/> </td><td><input 
          type='radio' name='mainmfts[{$key}]' value='Y'> Yes<input type='radio' 
          name='mainmfts[{$key}]' value='N'> No</td> </tr>";

        var existingRowCount =  x.closest("tr").length;
        var updatedCloneString = replaceAll(cloneData, '{$key}', existingRowCount);
        $(updatedCloneString).insertAfter(row);
    })               
 }
```

Hope it will help you. You need to ensure that every `input` should have different name.

Comment: As I read that's exactly the question: ensuring that every input has its unique name.

Comment: You can't paste the code and try to execute directly. It is just an approach to achieve desired output. Try to debug your code or make a fiddle so I can assist you further for this :)

Comment: can you explain to me what is the purpose of 'g' in var replaceAll?

Comment: `replace` only works for the first occurrence so it will only replace first `{$key}`. Thus we need to use regex to replace all `{$key}` with counter.

Comment: the replace is not working with me :/  I don't know what is the problem